# Flask - How to use CSS when i'm using Response(stream_template) with generator

Tags: python, css, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to learn Flask and making a small app. So at first, I tested without a css file by using: (delay() gets the result from generator)

```
return Response(stream_template('login.html', data=delay()))
```

It works fine for me then now i want to implement new css, let's called it style.css and i put it in the static folder. In the html file I have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}"/>
```

The code will probably won't work as there is a problem with context and response, but it will work fine as a static return:

```
return render_template('login.html')
```

My Question is it it anyway that I can both have the generator to work (the delay() function) with the CSS in the static folder? I just spent couple hours on this problem but couldn't find an answer yet.

My stream_template:

```
def stream_template(template_name, **context):
    app.update_template_context(context)
    t = app.jinja_env.get_template(template_name)
    rv = t.stream(context)
    # uncomment if you don't need immediate reaction
    ##rv.enable_buffering(5)
    return rv
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Where do you put that style tag? (top or bottom of template)

Comment: I put it in the top of the template like usual. When I use Response I get this : RuntimeError: Attempted to generate a URL without the application context being pushed. This has to be executed when application context is available.

Comment: See the answer i gave, i think it helps with your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from [the documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/streaming/#streaming-with-context):

> Note that when you stream data, the request context is already gone the moment the function executes. Flask 0.9 provides you with a helper that can keep the request context around during the execution of the generator: ...

In your case, your code probably should be:

```
return Response(stream_with_context(stream_template('login.html', data=delay())))
```

or

```
return Response(stream_template('login.html', data=stream_with_context(delay())))
```

Comment: interesting, i didn't think that we could use both stream_with_context and stream_template at the same time. Thank for the cod snippet it works so well.