# Streaming a template with static content with Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, werkzeug

I'm trying to stream a template using Flask, following [this example](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/streaming/). So, my `app.py` looks like:

```
from flask import Response

def stream_template(template_name, **context):
    app.update_template_context(context)
    t = app.jinja_env.get_template(template_name)
    rv = t.stream(context)
    rv.enable_buffering(5)
    return rv

@app.route('/my-large-page.html')
def render_large_template():
    rows = iter_all_rows()
    return Response(stream_template('the_template.html', rows=rows))
```

And my `the_template.html`:

```
<p>This is some static content:</p>
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='logo.png') }}"/>

<p>This is some streamed content:</p>
{% for row in rows %}
<p>{{ row }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

So far, the streaming works out just fine, **but the static content is not rendered until the stream is done**. How can I tell Flask to render both the stream and the static content as soon as the stream started?

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this?

```
from flask import Response, stream_with_context

return Response(stream_with_context(stream_template('the_template.html', rows=rows)))
```

I found this after going through all posts on stackoverflow and got it work.
In addition, I think you should use `yield` in `iter_all_rows()` function.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741833/flask-how-to-use-css-when-im-using-responsestream-template-with-generator/22742500#22742500)